# How do I run Telegram Desktop as a background process in dwm?

Tags: background-process, dwm

I want to run **Telegram Desktop** as a background process on **dwm**, such that I receive notifications when I have a new message and such that I don't have to keep the GUI open the entire time.

How would I go about that?

Whenever I close the GUI, the process closes entirely and I don't receive notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try patching it: https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/systray

By default DWM doesn't sport a systray where Telegram could be minimized to.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely try that patch out.